# Does anyone recognize this signature from Lord Rayleigh's "The Theory of Sound"?

Tags: symbols

I was reading from Rayleigh's "[The Theory of Sound](https://books.google.de/books/about/The_Theory_of_Sound.html?id=zTYIAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)" from 1877, and one of the first pages is dedicated to this signature which is given a proud position in the center of the page.

[image: Ornate signature/glyph]

Comment: Can you summarize what the book says about the signature ?

Comment: The book does not mention it in a single word, the book is all about the physics of sound.. It is like, just there, right on the first page after the title page, with no explanation at all.

Comment: [This](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/56187/56187-h/56187-h.htm) leads me to suspect that it is a mark of MacMillian Co.  Google image search for the win, although hat tip/FGW to @Evargalo

Comment: Looks more like a monogram than a signature.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This image seems to be the signature of the editing house, the [MacMillan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macmillan_Publishers) company. [image: official logo of MacMillan & Co]

[image: Title page of a book showing the Macmillan company symbol]

You can find other versions of their [logo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macmillan_Publishers#/media/File:MacMillan_and_Co_logo_1880.jpg) on their wikipedia [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macmillan_Publishers).